# Remove trailing zeros from decimal string

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have these numbers:

```
0.00000100
0.00100000
0.01000000
0.00001000
```

and I want to remove unnecessary zero in decimal by using this :

```
$decimal_cutter = (float) $decimal_cutter;
echo sprintf('%f', $decimal_cutter) . '<br>';
```

and it works for some numbers, some others produce this :

```
1.0E-6
0.001
0.01
1.0E-5
```

I want to use decimal, instead of scientific format.

Please note, I tried to use `number_format()` also, but keep in mind that by setting number of decimal points can cut the rest of numbers. I just want to remove the 0 after 1.

Comment: is your data always "1" or sometimes it's another number?

Comment: always '1', bro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you mention your data is always "1", here's a simple way:

```
$s = '0.00000100';
echo strstr($s, '1', true).'1';
```

Note: make sure you convert your data to string first

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply worried about not displaying those characters, why not simply `trim` them?

You can simply call `rtrim($yourNumber, '0')`

E.g.:

```
$a = [];

$a[] = "0.00000100";
$a[] = "0.00100000";
$a[] = "0.01000000";
$a[] = "0.00001000";

foreach ($a as $b) {
    echo rtrim($b, '0'), "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0.000001
0.001
0.01
0.00001
```

Logically this approach requires that you any of the decimal digits is different from `0`, otherwise a number such as `2.0000` would be displayed as `2.`, which might not be ideal.

You could build a more general purpose solution using `preg_replace`

```
$a = [];

$a[] = "0.00000100";
$a[] = "0.00100000";
$a[] = "0.01000000";
$a[] = "0.00001000";
$a[] = "2.00000000";
$a[] = "2.01011000";
$a[] = "0.00123000";

foreach ($a as $b) {
    echo preg_replace('|(?<!\.)0+$|', '', $b), "\n";
}
```

This looks for all trailing zeroes not preceded by a period, and would output:

```
0.000001
0.001
0.01
0.00001
2.0
2.01011
0.00123
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :

```
function clean_num( $num ){
    $pos = strpos($num, '.');
    if($pos === false) { // it is integer number
        return $num;
    }else{ // it is decimal number
        return rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.');
    }
}
```

source : http://web-profile.net/php/dev/php-remove-trailing-zeros/